# Перенаправление траффика

Tags: сеть, операторы

При покупке интернет пакета сотовый оператор дате бонусами несколько десяток гигабайта трафика только на социальные сети.

Возможно ли использовать этот трафик кроме соц сетей?

Для других нужд.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не относится к программированию.

Comment: Вероятно, у оператора стоит фильтр на определённые адреса - поэтому не получится, разве что оператор криво настроил - если очень хочется, можете попробовать самостоятельно, если ли дырка. Но помните: это не очень законно.

Comment: 1. Создаете свою социальную сеть. 2. Раскручиваете вою соцсеть до уровня вконтакте, одноклассников и т.п. 3. Убеждаете сотового оператора разрешить трафик и на вашу соцсеть. 4. Ставите внутри адресного пространства своей соцсети прокси и прогоняете через него трафик

Comment: @Mike Ахах Самый простой метод xD

Comment: Mike, походу вы "Остряк", вам бы в стендапах выступать. Если не знаешь ответ, то можно просто проигнорировать. Не обязательно показывать, что ты шут))